# Google API - Cross platform client credential authentication

Tags: android, ios, api, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

We are using a framework called LibGdx, which allows you to write cross-platform code using only Java. We are developing for Android and iOS.

We have a datastore in Google cloud, as well as an Google app engine api we made to communicate with this datastore.

Now we want to secure this API, but cannot find good guidance on how to approach this for cross-platform. Since we have a mix of fb-login and email-login we need to use client credentials (i.e only our app is allowed to communicate with our API).

Using .NET you would send client credentials (Client ID/Cleint secret), then get an access token, not sure how to approach that in this scenario. We do not have any scopes or anything like that, we just want to secure our API so it can't just be called by anyone. So a simple Bearer-token would solve our issues. Just not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should have a look at Firebase Authentication

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

Firebase supports several login providers like Google and Facebook. You will receive a token from Firebase Authentication which you have to forward to your API at Google App Engine.

You can use the Firebase Admin SDK at Google App Engine to validate the Token again

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Comment: Thanks, this does look interesting. Correct me if I'm wrong, but this would store our users in another location and simply give us a token back, we want to have the users in our own database since we have a ton of values that are unique to each user. Is this still possible?

Comment: when you receive the Firebase Token at Serverside, you need to check the validity of this token. The validation will send you back some Userinformation which you can store in your Google Datastore

Comment: It does look like it is what I need. Might even be worth just moving everything to firbase then, using their database instead of our own. That way dont even need an API.